# Positioning of image and panel in the header in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, header

The script generates a header Panel for my webpage which is displayed here:

[image: screenshot]

I want the OcC field to begin at the intersection of vertical and horizontal bar as shown. I am sure a margin: attribute can help me but don't know where to use it. Please help me and thanks.

```
<header>
<img src="C:/D DRIVE DATA/generic/logo.png" height="43" width="130">
height="43" width="130">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<nav class="navbar main-nav navbar-default ">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown OcC">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="100" data-
hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">OcC </a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown CoO ">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="100" data-
hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">CoO </a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown Fccc">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="100" data-
hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">Fccc</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown mpP">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="100" data-
hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">mpP</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown iR">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="100" data-
hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">iR</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown jko">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="100" data-
hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">jko</a>
</li></ul></li></ul></div></nav></div></div></header>
```

Comment: we are not able to see your image

Comment: @MaheswaranS We are now.

Comment: can u attach expected format in image?

Comment: @AK94 It might help if you posted the CSS you currently have as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I just want the header fields to begin at horizontal and vertical bar intersection. I have taken care of that image.

Comment: Please share the full html part, i need the left menu width.

Comment: Hey Maheswaran, can't thank you any lesser pal, but I kind of figured it out myself, some tweak in the CSS was needed. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @AK94 give a margin or same width as the sidebar.